# How to make a child element wider than its parent div, but not fill the entire browser width and be responsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, margin

I'm using negative margins to make a child element (`.alignwide` with width = 1000px) wider than its parent div (`.wrapper` with width = 800px), but I don't want it to fill the entire browser width.
This is the code I'm using:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="alignwide">
        This div expands beyond .wrapper parent margins. 
    <div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.wrapper {
    max-width: 800px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.alignwide {
    margin-left: calc((100% - 1000px) / 2);
    margin-right: calc((100% - 1000px) / 2);
    width: auto;
}
```

This is working if the browser window is wider than 1000px, but when I resize it to be narrower than 1000px, the `.alignwide` div is not responsive and its contents get cropped. Is there a way to make the `.alignwide` div narrower when reducing the browser width?

**UPDATE:** I'm adding two screenshots showing the behavior I'm looking for:

When the browser width is wider than 1000px:
[image]

When the browser width is narrower than 1000px:
[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you want the system of scrolling on child div when reached less than 1000px?

Comment: So what happens if the body is less than 1000px but more than 800px?

Comment: @Sunderam, no, I want it to be the same width as the browser width

Comment: you mean 100vw min-width;

Comment: I added two screenshots showing the behavior I'm looking for. I hope is clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `min()` to take the minimum value between 1000px and the screen width (100vw). I am using `margin-inline` which is as shorthand for left/right margin.

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin:auto;
}

.alignwide {
  margin-inline: calc((100% - min(100vw,1000px)) / 2);
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="alignwide">
    This div expands beyond .wrapper parent margins.
  </div>
</div>
```